# Simple ajax request not being sent, Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

My ajax request not being sent/received. Although normal GET request works fine.

html

```
 <a id="wish-add" href="javascript:" data-href="/plugins/e/wish/add/{{ object.id }}"> Add </a>
```

js

```
$('#wish-add').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
  url: $(this).attr('data-href'),
  success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
  },
  failure: function(data) {
      alert('Got an error dude');
  }
});
 return false;
});
```

views.py

```
class WishListAdd(FrontTemplateMixin, g.View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    raise Exception('a')
```

`Exception('a)` is never raised

Update

urls.py

```
Nurl(r'^wish/add/(?P<pid>\d+)/$', {'plugin_name': 'ecommerce'}) > 'plugins.ecommerce.wishlist.views.WishListAdd'
```

I think "url" works fine as it works when sending normal get request. Also I have tried setting ajax url to static url without `{{ object.id }}`, like so: `url: /plugins/e/wish/add/28` but no change.

Comment: where is your urls.py and the a tag should be like this
<a id="wish-add" href="/plugins/e/wish/add/{{ object.id }}" > Add </a>

Comment: In the template you could use url reverse resolvers: data-href="{% url 'view_name' object.id %}".  Also, you may have a js error, I think $(this).attr('data-href'), is not what you may think, try with $('#wish-add').attr('data-href'),

Answer (score 0):

We need to know more about your urls.py file, but common mistakes with urls:

- You did not write the urls path correctly.
- You did not include your app's urls in your project's urls.
- You  `{{ object.id }}` is null/empty/not exists.

Comment: Updated question for more details. The problem is `get` method from `class WishListAdd` is never being called